# Question regarding C#'s `List<>.ToString`

Tags: c#, list

Why doesn't C# `List<>`'s `ToString` method provide a sensible string representation that prints its contents? I get the class name (which I assume is the default `object.ToString` implementation) when I try to print a `List<>` object. Why is that so?

Comment: You wouldn't want an `OutOfMemoryException` for a large list.

Comment: @Ani: In that case, it can just print first few elements and then an ellipsis mark.

Comment: @missingfaktor: too intelligence for a method that 99.9% of times you won't use because you need the string in another way...

Comment: @missingfaktor ellipsis are bad because usually the idea is for ToString to be able to RoundTrip if there is a meaningful implementation. With ellipsis that would break. Let alone say that it would be useless without a way to specify when the ellipsis should be places. Moreover it's even more complicated because a list may contain a reference to itself in it's contents which would result in an infinite recursion when just ToStringing the content elements.

Answer (score 69, accepted):

The simple answer is: that's just the way it is, I'm afraid.

Likewise `List<T>` doesn't override `GetHashCode` or `Equals`. Note that it would have very little way of formatting pleasantly other than to call the simple `ToString` itself, perhaps comma-separating the values.

You could always write your own extension method to perform appropriate formatting if you want, or use the newer overloads of `string.Join` which make it pretty simple:

```
string text = string.Join(",", list);
```

Comment: Should this be string text = string.Join(',', list.ToArray()); ?

Comment: @Ryan: It depends whether or not the OP is using .NET 3.5 or .NET 4 - in .NET 4 there are more overloads for `string.Join`.

Comment: Just have List<T> (T1, T2, ...).ToString() return List<string> (T1.ToString(), T2.ToString(), ...)

Answer (score 3):

I think the reason is, that it is unclear what it should actualy do.

Maybe do ToString on ever elemenat and separate them with comas? But what if someone wants semicolons? Or dashes? Or someone wants to enclose whole string in curly or normal braclets? Or somone wants to use different function to get textual representation of single element?

Few things to note: ToString should be used only for debuging purpouses. If you want to export your data into string, either override this behaviour in your class or make an utility class for it.

Also List is intended to store elements, not to provide their textual representation.

Comment: Having an easily useable default representation does not stop anyone from overriding or making utility classes. Other languages can poll the members of a list for appropriate strings. C# ints return sensible strings from ToString(), and Console.WriteLine() can even figure out how to get this from just the variable name. Hearing about how Java can do it in another comment, coming from Python, and seeing how string manipulation is easier than C++, I assumed C# could handle it. I guess for containers it's closer to Python's __repr__() than __str__(). I'll watch out for more of this inconsistency.

Answer (score 2):

Because it's probably not that easy to implement.

A `List<>` can contain a lot of stuff. For example another `List<>` that contains a `Dictionary<>` that contains complex objects...

Comment: @gsharp: Java's `List` provides it. What do you have to say about that?

Comment: @missing: That C# is not the same language as Java. Not really sure what that question was supposed to mean.

Comment: @Cody: That was a rhetorical question to imply that reasons mentioned by @gsharp cannot really be the reasons, as there exists an eminent counterexample in the form of Java.

Comment: C# folks should definitely be gracious and let the Java guys claim victory on this one. It's the kind thing to do... after all, Java sucks so appallingly in many other ways! :)

Comment: guys.... i was just kidding.... don't let's start another c# vs. java war again. both languages are great.

Comment: @Daniel: Agree. @gsharp: I'd say both of them suck. :P </flamebait>

Comment: @missingfaktor. lol... okay, okay... compared with VB6 everything sucks :-p

Comment: Actually it's very easy. If you have doubts, look at Java :)