# c# ToList() and ToString()

Tags: c#

I'm debugging a query with `.SingleOrDefault()` that's throwing an exception "subquery is returning more than one element."

```
SomeValue = (from...
             where ....
             select ...).SingleOrDefault()
```

I want to see for which value it's generating this bug so I changed it to this:

```
SomeValue = ((from...
              where ....
              select ...).ToList()).ToString()
```

The problem is that it's not returning a string of the list but it's returning `"System.Collections.Generic.List1[System.String]"`

How do I get the list to a string of elements separate by commas?

Thanks.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Question regarding C#'s `List<>.ToString`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5050507/question-regarding-cs-list-tostring)

Comment: You have two opening parens there `((from...` -- only one is needed.  (`.ToList().ToString()` is already sufficient)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
SomeValue = string.Join( ",", (from... where... select...) )
```

Comment: The `.ToList()` isn't even needed there.