# How to add an instantiated object to list and print the list to the console

Tags: c#

Working on an assignment and need a little help. I'm trying to have the user input their list of fun places to visit and as they add the places I want to save it to a list and then give them the option to view the entire list of places. I'm having trouble saving the objects to a list:

```
using System;
using static System.Console;

namespace Assignment_4
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main()
        {
            Test.DisplayInstructions();
            Test.AddPlace();

            WriteLine("Would you like to add another place, Y/N?");
            var addAnother = ReadKey().KeyChar;;

            switch (char.ToLower(addAnother))
            {
                case 'y':
                    Test.AddPlace();
                    break;
                case 'n':
                    break;
                default:
                    break;
            }

            WriteLine("Would you like to see your list of fun places? Y/N");
            var reviewList = ReadKey().KeyChar;
            switch (char.ToLower(reviewList))
            {
                case 'y':
                    WriteLine(Test.funPlacesList);
                    break;
                case 'n':
                    break;
                default:
                    break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This is the test I run to check the program:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using static System.Console;
namespace Assignment_4
{
    public class Test
    {

        internal static void DisplayInstructions()
        {
          WriteLine("Welcome to my application: \n This app will you write about your favorite places \n" +
          "To begin we'll need you to provide the information as prompted \n" +
          "The app will then take that info and display it back to you. Showing you your favorite place!");
        }


        public static List<FunPlace> funPlacesList = new List<FunPlace>();



        internal static void AddPlace()
        {
            FunPlace place = new FunPlace();
            WriteLine("What is the name of this place?");
            place.PlaceName = ReadLine();
            WriteLine("Where is it located?");
            place.PlaceAddress = ReadLine();
            WriteLine("What kinds of fun things can you do there?");
            place.PlaceDescription = ReadLine();
            WriteLine("Any additional Comments to add?");
            place.PlaceComments = ReadLine();
            WriteLine("Provide a rating from 0.0 - 5.0.");
            place.PlaceRating = float.Parse(ReadLine());

            funPlacesList.Add(place);

            ReadKey();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You should use a loop to list all places in the funPlacesList on this line: WriteLine(Test.funPlacesList);

Comment: _I'm having trouble saving the objects to a list_ Can you describe what kind of trouble that you are having?

Comment: @MartinLiversage My main issue is instantiate a new object using the users input and then adding that to the list of places. It doesn't come out right when i run it through the terminal

Comment: I imagine you're seeing something like `System.Collections.Generic.List\`1[FunPlace]`?

Comment: @St.Pat You hit the nail on the head!

Comment: `WriteLine(string.Join(Environment.NewLine, Test.funPlacesList.Select(p => p.PlaceName)));`

Comment: Then Craig's answer is the one you want, you're seeing the `Object.ToString()` result, which is just the type's name printed out

Comment: You also might want to consider adding an override to ToString on your `FunPlace` class. Something like: `public override string ToString() { return this.PlaceName; }`. If you do that, then you could just do `Test.funPlacesList.ForEach(Console.WriteLine);`

Comment: @St.Pat That was it! Out of curiosity why does it print the type and not the list as a whole?

Comment: I would place my guess on that it could get potentially messy depending on what's in the collection. If it's a list of dictionaries, each of which have a list as a value, and this innermost list has complex objects for example. It could also be as simple as, [that's just the way it is](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5050507/question-regarding-cs-list-tostring)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks to me like you're adding to the list just fine. You can't just `Console.WriteLine(funPlacesList)` though, all you're going to get is the name of the class. You need to loop over the collection and write out each entry individually.

```
foreach(var funPlace in Test.funPlacesList)
{
    WriteLine(funPlace.PlaceName);
    WriteLine(funPlace.PlaceAddress);
    // etc...
}
```

Comment: This was exactly what I needed! Much Appreciated

Answer (score 1):

```
foreach (FunPlace place in Test.funPlacesList)
{
    Console.Writeline(place.PlaceName);
}
```

Is this what you were looking for? `foreach` can be used to loop through a collection of objects(list, array etc.) and reference each one inside the foreach block as `place` in this example.

For the record, I highly recommend coming up with another name for your Test class. Good names are a crucial long-term investment in the ease of understanding your code.

Comment: Unless he overrides `ToString()` in `FunPlace`, he will end up with the same issue. It will print the fully qualified class name.